# regex to find substring between special characters

Tags: java, regex

I am running into this problem in Java.

I have data strings that contain entities enclosed between `&` and `;` For e.g.

```
&Text.ABC;, &Links.InsertSomething;
```

These entities can be anything from the ini file we have.

I need to find these string in the input string and remove them. There can be none, one or more occurrences of these entities in the input string.

I am trying to use regex to pattern match and failing.

Can anyone suggest the regex for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the regex:

```
"&[A-Za-z]+(\\.[A-Za-z]+)*;"
```

It starts by matching the character `&`, followed by one or more letters (both uppercase and lower case) (`[A-Za-z]+`). Then it matches a dot followed by one or more letters (`\\.[A-Za-z]+`). There can be any number of this, including zero. Finally, it matches the `;` character.

You can use this regex in java like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&[A-Za-z]+(\\.[A-Za-z]+)*;"); // java.util.regex.Pattern
String subject = "foo &Bar; baz\n";
String result = p.matcher(subject).replaceAll("");
```

Or just

```
"foo &Bar; baz\n".replaceAll("&[A-Za-z]+(\\.[A-Za-z]+)*;", "");
```

If you want to remove whitespaces after the matched tokens, you can use this re:

```
"&[A-Za-z]+(\\.[A-Za-z]+)*;\\s*" // the "\\s*" matches any number of whitespace
```

Answer (score 1):

And there is a nice online regular expression tester which uses the java regexp library.

http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
input=input.replaceAll("&[^.]+\\.[^;]+;(,\\s*&[^.]+\\.[^;]+;)*","");
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/hEvy4)